# create a new array from array of arrays

Tags: javascript

I have this array of arrays:

```
let a = [

["i was sent", "i do"],
["i was sent", "i sent"],
["to protect you", "to find you"]

]
```

And I want to return this single array from it:

```
b = ["i was sent = i do", "i was sent = i sent", "to protect you = to find you"]
```

How can I do that?

I have tried to use a map like `let b = a.map(s => s + ' = ');` but it won't do the job?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge/flatten an array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays)

Comment: In your `map` statement, debug and check what `s` is. You'll find it's an array of two strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let a = [
  ["i was sent", "i do"],
  ["i was sent", "i sent"],
  ["to protect you", "to find you"]
]

let result = a.map(x => x.join(" = "))
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your inner arrays always have two elements:

```js
let a = [

["i was sent", "i do"],
["i was sent", "i sent"],
["to protect you", "to find you"]

]

let b = a.map(el => `${el[0]} = ${el[1]}`);

console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a for loop to iterate through the array, and joining each of the 2nd dimensional arrays. You could use something like this:

`for(var i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++) {
array[i] = array[i][0] + " = " + array[i][1];
}`

Answer (score 1):

mine...

```js
let a = 
    [ [ "i was sent", "i do"] 
    , [ "i was sent", "i sent"] 
    , [ "to protect you", "to find you"] 
    ] 

const jojo=([x,y])=>x+' = '+y

let b = a.map(jojo)

console.log ( b )
```